# .NET Core Singleton service instance in Web Controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am fairly new .NET, so pardon my ignorance, and I am trying to learning more .NET Core now.

I have, for instance, a user service which is used in a WebApi Controller. Is it safe to register the user service as a singleton, or do I need to register it as scoped? My concern is that if multiple users call the same endpoint, for instance /users/me, it might return each others information. Is that the case, or is it safe to use a singleton service to retrieve such data from the database? I get the user's Id from the http context, and use userService.FindById(userId) to retrieve the data. I can't seem to find this information from the lifecycle docs. Thanks

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself: Why do you want a user service to be singleton? Do you have state in them you want to persist over the request? If so, its a horrible approach as http is stateless by default. Are you doing computationally expensive stuff in your service constructor? this is wrong too as constructors should be fast. If you follow this two rules of thumb (no states over multiple requests and no heavy computation in constructor) you'll rarely find yourself a need for singletons

Comment: In the cases you need, us the appropriate mechanisms (session or `IMemoryCache`/`IDistributedCache`). Singletons are good, if you have something thats thread safe and can handle multiple requests (i.e. http client, redis client etc. You dont want these on per request basis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no, it won't be an issue. Based on the simplistic description, there's no chance of cross-over. However, if you're doing some sort of caching or otherwise persisting user info to the class in any way (such as setting an ivar), you could have issues. Generally speaking, if aside from any dependencies you are injecting into the constructor, the class could otherwise be made static and still work, you're fine. If you're doing anything internally that would prevent making the class static, then there's a good chance you're leaking.

That said, if your service has dependencies on scoped services, it should be scoped itself. With something like a "users" service, there's a good chance you're going to be relying on something like an EF context or `UserManager<TUser>`, etc. Those are scoped, so with your service as a singleton, you'll be forced to employ the service-locator anti-pattern and you'll also likely be doing things inefficiently in general trying to work around the dependencies having a shorter lifetime than the service itself. It's best in such a scenario to make your service scoped, allowing you to injected scoped dependencies directly.

There seems to be a naive idea that the default or preferred lifetime should be singleton for things like services, repos, etc. In fact, the opposite is true: you should prefer scoped unless there's a good explicit reason to do otherwise. For example, if you're trying to coordinate some set of tasks across threads using something like `SemaphoreSlim`, that's a fairly obvious scenario that would require a singleton lifetime. Unless you're doing something like that truly requires a singleton lifetime, use a scoped lifetime instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification :-)